# ffmpeg: Using tee with segmenter

Tags: ffmpeg, tee

I'm trying to use a tee to output my stream into 1min segments and into a file at the same time. Here's my command:

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://${cameraIp}:554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&resolution=1280x720&fps=15" -c copy -map 0 \
-f tee "[f=ssegment:segment_time=60:segment_format=mp4:reset_timestamps=1:r=15] ${rootPath}/${storeId}-${location}-%03d.mp4 \
| /tmp/${cameraIp}.mkv"
```

Individually (without tee) both outputs work fine. So I can either output into segmented files or into a non-segmented file. But with the tee I get this error:

> [stream_segment,ssegment @ 0x217ece0] Failed to open segment '
>   /etc/cida/diagnostics/vid/780801-99-000.mp4' [tee @ 0x217d820] Slave
>   '[f=ssegment:segment_time=60:segment_format=mp4:reset_timestamps=1:r=15]
>   /etc/cida/diagnostics/vid/780801-99-%03d.mp4': error writing header:
>   No such file or directory

See full command output below. Any suggestions?

> ffmpeg version 3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
>   built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)   configuration:
>   --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab --enable-libwavpack --enable-nvenc   libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100   libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100   libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100   libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100   libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100   libavresample   3.  5.  0 / 
>   3.  5.  0   libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100   libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100   libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100 Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://10.83.245.7:554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&resolution=1280x720&fps=15':
>   Metadata:
>       title           : Session streamed with GStreamer
>       comment         : rtsp-server   Duration: N/A, start: 0.080011, bitrate: N/A
>       Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
>   [stream_segment,ssegment @ 0x217ece0] Failed to open segment '
>   /etc/cida/diagnostics/vid/780801-99-000.mp4' [tee @ 0x217d820] Slave
>   '[f=ssegment:segment_time=60:segment_format=mp4:reset_timestamps=1:r=15]
>   /etc/cida/diagnostics/vid/780801-99-%03d.mp4': error writing header:
>   No such file or directory [tee @ 0x217d820] Slave muxer #0 failed,
>   aborting. Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec
>   parameters ?): No such file or directory Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0
>   -> #0:0 (copy)
>       Last message repeated 1 times

Comment: I was trying to edit this so that it's not garbled nonsense, but I have up.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example that may help you or someone else.

I'm recording video from a vga to usb capture device in 1 hour segments and also streaming to UDP, which is then streamed using VLC (cvlc) as a rtp stream to a multicast address.  That way, multi people can watch the live video (about a 5 second delay) if needed.

Here is the command line:

```
ffmpeg -rtbufsize 500M -f v4l2 -video_size 1152x900 -i /dev/video0 \
  -vf "drawtext='fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSans.ttf:text=%{localtime}: x=10: y=10: fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=black@1: fontsize=24'" \
  -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 28 \
  -pix_fmt yuv420p -an -r 15 -y \
  -f tee -map 0:v "[f=segment:segment_atclocktime=1:segment_time=3600:strftime=1]/videos/raw_video/video_%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.mp4|[f=mpegts]udp://127.0.0.1:1234/"
```

The OS is Ubuntu 16.04 MATE.

Comment: just wanted to say, that is one beautiful command. The versatility of ffmpeg never ceases to amaze me.